# android - xml deserialization like Views

Tags: java, android, xml

New to Android.

In this page of the Android documentation

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#subclassview

they discuss how you can create a View class which can be instantiated from Activity xml. To make this work :

1) your View extender class implements the myView(Context, AttributeSet) constructor.

2) Then, in res/values/attrs.xml, you create an `<declare-styleable>` declaration for the parameters your view accepts.

3) Then, you create xml tags in your Activity xml like `<com.me.myView attrib1="" attrib2=""/>` using the attributes defined in step 2.

Is there a way to use this mechanism not in the context of creating Views? What I would like to do is create a class with a specialized constructor for this purpose. Then, I'd like to create some xml file(s) either in res/ or assets/. Finally, I'd like to be able to say, `myobjects[] = android.deserializemyfile(assets/file1.xml)`.

Not surprised if I'm missing something basic here, I just started with Android today.

Thank you !

[[ EDIT ]]

It sounds like JAXB is the secret sauce I'm looking for. My application will do this at startup so performance is not much of an issue.

[[ EDIT ]]

Nevermind, JAXB is not included in Android, and is very large. SimpleXML has licensing restrictions. I have found this :

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson

open-source, and a tiny footprint as an external library.